# Showing message issue

Tags: jquery

Selected multiple rows from a grid, for example 5 records. When I click on a button (caption - Assign)  I want to show the message box for first item and have to do the assign functionality and show the success message.  After that show the next message box for the second item and do the functionality for assign and show the successmessage, and continue the above process for the whole 5 items. But Now my problem is :

I have a for loop, inside that loop messagebox function there to show message. But it is executed the whole at a time, and show only one messagebox. We are  showing message is in a div.

This is the function to call the showing message box in a loop.

```
    $("#DwgEquipmentAssignBlock").on("click", function (e)
{

    e.preventDefault();
    var totalSelectedIds="";
    var selectedcount =  getWijGridSelectedRowCount("Grid1"); 
    if(selectedcount !=0)
    {         

        for (var i = 0; i < selectedcount; i++)
        {           
            var okReturn=showAlert("Select a Block to assign the selected Equipment");
            okReturn.okClick = function()
            {
                console.log('Value of i' + i);   // I got only one console result as the count. (the total count)
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Show messagebox function :

```
function showAlert(msg) {//Messagebox with out grid page

var showAlerObject = {};
showAlerObject.$dvMessageBox = $("#dvMessageBox");
showAlerObject.$dialogboxForMessage = $('#dialogboxForMessage');
showAlerObject.$dvMessageBox.html(msg);
$(".ui-widget").css({ "font-weight": +"bold" });
showAlerObject.$dialogboxForMessage.dialog({
    title: 'Edu Plus',
    showOnLoad: false,
    autoExpand: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 370,
    modal: true,
    close: function () {

        showAlerObject.$dialogboxForMessage.dialog('destroy');
        showAlerObject.$dvMessageBox.html('');
    },
    buttons: {

        OK: function () {
            if (showAlerObject.okClick !== null) {
                showAlerObject.okClick();
            }
            showAlerObject.$dialogboxForMessage.dialog('destroy');
            showAlerObject.$dvMessageBox.html('');
        }
    },
    show: 'fade',
    hide: 'fade',
    dialogClass: 'main-dialog-class'
});
showAlerObject.$dialogboxForMessage.dialog("open"); 
return showAlerObject;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer : In  OK: function - first destroy and clear the html and proceed. That is the only change that we need to implement.

```
    function showAlert(msg) {//Messagebox with out grid page
    var showAlerObject = {};
    showAlerObject.$dvMessageBox = $("#dvMessageBox");
    showAlerObject.$dialogboxForMessage = $('#dialogboxForMessage');
    showAlerObject.$dvMessageBox.html(msg);
    $(".ui-widget").css({ "font-weight": +"bold" });
    showAlerObject.$dialogboxForMessage.dialog({
     title: 'Edu Plus',
     showOnLoad: false,
     autoExpand: false,
     autoOpen: false,
     width: 370,
     modal: true,
close: function () {
    showAlerObject.$dialogboxForMessage.dialog('destroy');
    showAlerObject.$dvMessageBox.html('');
},
  buttons: {
        OK: function () {
            showAlerObject.$dialogboxForMessage.dialog('destroy');
            showAlerObject.$dvMessageBox.html('');
            if (showAlerObject.okClick !== null) {
                showAlerObject.okClick();
            }                
        }
    },
     show: 'fade',
     hide: 'fade',
     dialogClass: 'main-dialog-class'
    });
    showAlerObject.$dialogboxForMessage.dialog("open"); 
    return showAlerObject;
    }
```